# Could not find local variable while debugging in Android studio (2.1.3)

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I am using android studio 2.1.3 and gradle version 2.14.1 along with java version 1.8. The problem is, I'm not able to find values of local variables while debugging.

Here's the `defaultConfig` used in `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
    applicationId "com.example.sss"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Could you post a copy of the code that is not complying? I think that would be more helpful than your gradle file.

Comment: I've removed the un-necessary parts from the question. Please post the necessary code segment which you want to debug so that others can help finding the problem.

Comment: @ReazMurshed actually, `build.config` can be a problem here

Comment: I suppose you tried to remove `jackOptions` from `defaultConfig` and enable it only for release buildType?

Comment: @Alvenir Thank you for the comment. I've added the necessary parts back.

Comment: @Alvenir if we removed the jackOption from default config then it we give compile time error where we are using functional interface as well as where we are using expression of Java 1.8

Answer (score 0):

In your Gradle file do you have:

```
testCoverageEnabled true
```

If so, you need to set that value to false:

```
testCoverageEnabled false
```